# CSS change two links when hovering over either one of them

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="home" class="section">
        <ul>
            <li class="home_li"><a href="#home" class="goto_home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="about_li"><a href="#about" class="goto_about">About us</a></li>
            <li class="contact_li"><a href="#contact" class="goto_contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  <!-- End home -->

    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="home_li"><a href="#home" class="goto_home"></a></li>
            <li class="about_li"><a href="#about" class="goto_about"></a></li>
            <li class="contact_li"><a href="#contact" class="goto_contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  <!-- End nav -->
</div>  <!-- End main -->
```

What I'm trying to do is change the state of both links when one is being hovered.  For example, if I hover over 'about' under `<div id="home">` I want both links, that one and the one under `<div id="nav">`, to be displayed with opacity.

I'm trying to stay away from JS if possible.  So far my attempt with CSS has been with adjacent selectors but that's new to me so I haven't been able to make it work.

```
    #home .about_li a:hover + #nav .about_li a {
        opacity: .5;
    }
```

Can this be done with only CSS?

EDIT:

Thanks for your replies.  How would I need to change the HTML for the adjacent selector to work?  I could give it a try and make a few tweaks if it doesn't affect seriously the rest of the site (the structure is pretty much complete by now).

ANOTHER EDIT:

Okay, I've read some more about these selectors and now I get it.  I'd thought that by being all inside the main div they were siblings :P and now I see why it doesn't work.  I'll see if I can come up with a workaround to use only CSS and will post back here.  Otherwise I'll go with JS :(

Comment: What you have doesn't work because your CSS rule is looking for for an a tag under #nav that is an adjacent sibling of the other a tag under #home. I think you need JS to do it.

Comment: CSS really can't do this. Even if drastically changing the HTML was an option, you wouldn't be able to make the first link change when you hover over the second. Surrender to the jQuery!

Comment: @brunn: http://jsfiddle.net/hweEr/4/

Comment: @thirtydot: "Even if drastically changing the HTML was an option" ?

Comment: @Jawad: That's not "drastically changed", it's *completely freaking different*. Though it does work :) Whether it can be used for real depends on what the actual page looks like.

Comment: @thirtydot: Can't arugue with that. Though you are right!

Comment: @Jawad That's awesome! I'll give it a try and see if I can make it work with the rest of the site.

Comment: @thirtydot And to think I almost surrender to jquery :P

Comment: @brunn: Well, it could be a *single line* of jQuery-powered JavaScript. Using jQuery is easier than trying to bend your HTML and CSS in crazy ways. jQuery will be downloaded once and cached. If you use a CDN version, users are likely to already have it cached.

Comment: Well, I gave it a try but didn't work with my layout so jQuery here I go.  However Jawad's example was really nice and I'll try it again in the future.  Thanks everyone for your input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your structure is too complex for CSS selectors alone, as the `a` elements aren't siblings of each other, but it's your inner `div`s, and so on.

It's very easy with JavaScript libraries like jQuery, otherwise you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

no, if you are not going to change HTML structure, or you can use jQuery

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with CSS; although I applaud your efforts to stay away from loading a bunch of JS, especially heavyweight libraries.