# How to change one element while hovering over another with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have looked at several other questions but I can't seem to figure any of them out, so here is my problem: I would like to have a `div` or a `span`, when you hover over it an area would appear and would be like a drop down.

Such as I have an `div`, and I want to hover over it and have it show some info about the item I hovered over

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Question1</title>
<styles type="css/text">

  #cheetah {
      background-color: red;
      color: yellow;
      text-align: center;
  }

  a {
      color: blue;
  }

  #hidden {
      background-color: black;
   }

   a:hover > #hidden {
      background-color: orange;
      color: orange;
  }
</styles>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="cheetah">
     <p><a href="#">Cheetah</a></p>
  </div>
  <div id="hidden">
     <p>A cheetah is a land mammal that can run up 2 60mph!!!</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this ^ doesn't seem to work, I don't know why... and if there is a way to do that in CSS, I would like to know, but I want any and all suggestions.

Comment: See my comments at the bottom of the question. There is also a fiddle there. If the option of chnaging your html structure is a option - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669147/css-change-two-links-when-hovering-over-either-one-of-them

Comment: in jquery http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/e8wJb/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can achieve this in CSS only if the hidden div is a child of the element you use for hovering:

http://jsfiddle.net/LgKkU/

Answer (score 17):

You cannot affect a non-child element using `:hover` from within CSS2, which is supported by all common browsers.

You can affect a sibling element using CSS2.1 selectors, like so:

```
a:hover + .sibling { ... }
```

However, this only works for **direct siblings**.  This means you could have HTML like this:

```
<p><a href="#">Cheetah</a> <span class="sibling">Blah Blah Blah</span></p>
```

Notice that the `a` and the `span` are direct siblings.

Here's a fiddle showing the siblings working: http://jsfiddle.net/vUUxp/

However, [not all browsers support the CSS2.1 sibling selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2), so you need to decide based on your target audience if you can use this or not.

**Edit**: Corrected my mistake on the CSS version for the `+` selector: it's 2.1 that defines it, not CSS3.  I also added a link showing browser support.  Otherwise, the answer is the same.

Comment: There are also [general sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), but they also work only for subsequent elements

Answer (score 9):

Or, if you're open to it, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Something like this would work:

```
$("#element") // select your element (supports CSS selectors)
    .hover(function(){ // trigger the mouseover event
        $("#otherElement") // select the element to show (can be anywhere)
            .show(); // show the element
    }, function(){ // trigger the mouseout event
        $("#otherElement") // select the same element
            .hide(); // hide it
    });
```

And remember to wrap this in a DOM ready function (`$(function(){...});` or `$(document).ready(function(){...});`).

Answer (score 5):

You can absolutely do this in CSS3 now using the `~` adjacent sibling selector.

```
triggerSelector:hover ~ targetSelector {
    display: block;
}
```

For example, if you want a tooltip to appear when hovering over an adjacent button:

```
.button:hover ~ .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```