# How to make a:hover also control img background?

Tags: html, css, hover, background-color

I think I need the help of a wiser Front End coding Ninja today.

So right now I have some social media icons in my header where on rollover I want the img background color of the icons to change as well as the text color.

Now the way I have my li's setup both items (icon background and text color) will change if I rollover the icon images, however it does not happen when I only roll over the text. When I rollover only the text link, only the text color changes and not the icon background.

You can see this here:
http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/

**Current HTML:**

```
<div id="social_media">
    <ul id="social_icons">
        <li class="mail_chimp"><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://athenasweb.us5.list-manage.com/subscriber-count?b=37&amp;u=d789790b-2a29-4119-8a43-0d71267eb0d7&amp;id=bc095e8eb4"></script></li>
        <a href="#" title="Subscribe to our Newsletter"><li class="social_li ico_newsletter"><p class="float-left">Get Email Newsletter</p><img src="http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/img/ico_newsletter.png" alt="Newsletter"/></a></li>
        <a href="http://facebook.com/athenasweb" title="Like our Facebook Page"><li class="social_li ico_facebook"><p class="float-left">Our Facebook Page</p><img src="http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/img/ico_facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/></a></li>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/athenas_web" title="Follow on Twitter"><li class="social_li ico_twitter"><p class="float-left">Follow us on Twitter</p><img src="http://s433108212.onlinehome.us/img/ico_twitter.png" alt="Twitter"/></a></li>
        <!-- <li><p>RSS Feed</p><img src="img/icon_rss.png" alt="RSS"/></li> -->
    </ul>
</div><!-- social_media -->
```

Current CSS:

```
.social_li { list-style-type:none; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; line-height:     32px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer; }
.social_li a { color:#4098db; }
.social_li a:hover { color:#fff; }
.social_li p { float: right; text-align: left; }

.ico_newsletter img, .ico_facebook img, .ico_twitter img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #cc0033;
    background-position:top center;
}
.ico_newsletter img {
    background: #cc0033;
}
.ico_facebook img {
    background: #064771;
}
.ico_twitter img {
    background: #00aced;
}
.social_li img:hover { 
    background: #666;
}
```

Now I thought I needed to update this line:

```
.social_li a:hover { color:#fff; }
```

I tried:

```
.social_li a:hover { color:#fff; background:#666; }
```

However that produced this result when I rolled over just the text:
[image]

I believe that's because I can't make the a:hover control the specific img background.

Has anyone else tried this before? Thoughts? :)

Comment: Do you have access to jQuery?

Comment: Your HTML is heinous. Please clean it up. :S

Comment: you can do this by CSS3 also by doing animation in it...

Comment: @JSKNS yes I can I use, and I'll try the jQuery solution linked below thx! iambriansreed could you be a bit more specific? What areas or what in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the top two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another).

Basically, jQuery might be your best option.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I didn't have to use jQuery in this instance, but oh well :)

Comment: I was kind've hoping someone would post a better solution than jQuery myself.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you should use here is [sprite sheets](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

For example; on my site I have some social icons in the footer, which are all made up of this image:

[image]

What I've done here is set the top row to contain the standard images, and the bottom row to contain the rollover states.

What you could do to have the text colour and image change is first create your container for both the image, which will be a background image, and the text:

```
<a href="#facebook" class="social fb">
    <div></div>
    Facebook
</a>
```

Then some CSS:

```css
a.social
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
}

a.social:hover
{
    color: #F00;
}

a.social > div
{
    height: 20px;
    background: url(http://martywallace.com/view/textures/sprite/social.png) no-repeat;
}

a.social.fb > div
{
    background-position: -15px 0;
}


/* Notice here how we target the child div of the a element being hovered over. */
a.social.fb:hover > div
{
    /* We change the background-position to sample a new portion of the sprite. */
    background-position: -15px -20px;
}
```

I've created a complete example with both social icons at this [JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gd4ha/)](http://jsfiddle.net/gd4ha/).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I thought about Sprite-sheets too, but in my case I have transparent icons. And using CSS to create circle backgrounds so I can just change the background color to create the animation. I have to finish up the rest of the site, but I'll come back to this!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the text is lower-level in the code than the images, so while changes applied to the images can also affect the text, the converse is not true.  Have you tried using Javascript to change the image on mouse-over action of the text?

```
document.getElementByClassName("your-classname-here").setAttribute("class","new-classname-here");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would include the icon background color as part of the icon itself. Have 2 versions of the icon, one with the standard bg color, one with the gray bg.  Then make the icons background images on the list items and simply swap the background image when the list item is hovered over.  Changes the whole approach to this bit of code, but I think it would work better.

Answer (score 0):

While the image and the text inside of it are clearly just one element (a button) to you, from CSS' point of view (depending on exactly how it's coded) they will often appear to be two separate elements.

'a:hover' is a special case of 'a' and applies only to 'anchor' (<a ...) statements. You also have an 'image' (<img ...) statement and so will also need 'img:hover'. (You know they're related, but CSS doesn't.:-)

You've also misspelled the attribute name as 'background' where it should be 'background-color'.

So to do this entirely in CSS you may need some awkward-looking code with two separate statements, like:

.social_li a:hover { color:#fff; }

.social_li img:hover { background-color:#666; }

In any case, by default images specify *every* pixel, and no color shows through. (Another way to think of this is CSS has no idea which parts of the image you consider the "background.") You may need to get 'semi-transparent' (every other pixel shows through) or 'transparent' (every pixel shows through in selected areas) images.

Or perhaps you would do better with a completely different approach: perhaps as noted in another response separate 'up' and 'down' images swapped by Javascript, or perhaps highlight only the *border* around the button leaving its interior unchanged, or perhaps change the color of only the text, or perhaps a semi-transparent scrim laid over top of each button that you can color, or perhaps ...