# Sibling Selector (tilde) Issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to modify named elements in my design. I've simplified the situation as you can see in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6THpF/

Simply, when I try to modify one named element from the other, it works, but when I try to do the same modification from the opposite direction (other element) it does not work.

Here is the sample code:

```
body{
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

#div_one, #div_two{
    background-color:darkred;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:30px;
    margin:10px;
    color:white;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;

}
#div_one:hover ~ #div_two{
    background-color:red;
}
#div_two:hover ~ #div_one{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: This is a stretch, but depending on how closely contained the divs are inside a parent, you could do something like http://jsfiddle.net/z2yTv/

Comment: THank you for this reply! Actually, the ":not" selector is really meaningfull in this case, however, what I directly want to do is: to colorize the background of my "logo" when a third-level menu button "start" is hovered. I guess I'll need something more defined than this, something like a direct id selector or a class selector, or anything that can do a similar job.

Comment: If I'm guessing correctly, your page is structured so that this menu is visually below the logo? Perhaps put the menu above the logo in your HTML, then use absolute positioning to adjust for the proper visual effect. That way, the sibling combinator will actually match properly.

Comment: Various buttons will colorize various elements differently; that's where everything gets tricky..

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

So since `div_one` is not preceded by `div_two` the second rule won't work. In other words, there is no "previous sibling" selector.

Comment: I see... Is there any way to select a sibling with id or class name? (that will solve my situation above)

Comment: With pure CSS, no. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another

Answer (score 1):

Try this.I answered:
HTML:

```
<div id="div_one">This is div 1</div>
<div id="div_two">This is div 2</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

#div_one, #div_two{
    background-color:darkred;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:30px;
    margin:10px;
    color:white;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;

}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div_one").mouseover(function(){
    $("#div_two").css("backgroundColor","blue");
    });
    $("#div_one").mouseout(function(){
    $("#div_two").css("backgroundColor","darkred");
    });
    $("#div_two").mouseover(function(){
    $("#div_one").css("backgroundColor","blue");
    });
    $("#div_two").mouseout(function(){
    $("#div_one").css("backgroundColor","darkred");
    });
    });
```

remember that use and embed the `jquery.js` core to your web page.

Comment: Thank you! I know this sounds like a challenge but I'm looking for a css-only workaround for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not solving the sibling selector issue (that I think that can not be solved), but the effect intended.
You need to group both divs in one:

```
<div>
    <div id="div_one">This is div 1</div>
    <div id="div_two">This is div 2</div>
</div>
```

and now target the hover state of the group div:

```
div:hover #div_two{
background-color:red;
}
div:hover #div_one{
background-color:red;
}
```

of course the later can be written better, (or shorter) I just wanted to change as little as possible in your example

This has some drawbacks that you may be will need to address.

If you want the divs to have space between them (and this space not responsive to the hover), then I think that you will need to change them to absolute positioning.

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgsZm/3/)

**edited**

I missed the requirement about not hovering the hovered div. Change css to

```
div:hover #div_two:not(:hover){
background-color:red;
}
div:hover #div_one:not(:hover){
background-color:red;
}
```

Now I think it's what you wanted [edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/hgsZm/5/)

Comment: THank you for the reply, however, this does not have the original idea of "mouse overing one element and changing the other one".

Comment: Now it's the same with joequincy's answer! the usage of "not" is nice however what I need is directly modifying the element (this answer won't work with 3 elements)