# CSS - show element E1 when hovered over element E2

Tags: css, html, hover

This is a weird question but I was given an html file to work with and it has B tag for the title and seperate ol tag for the list.

something like this

```
<b> Title of the list </b>
<ol>
    <li> List item 1 </li>
    <li> list item 2 </li>
</ol>
```

What I would like to do is, show the list when hovered over the title. How do I do this?

right now this is what I have.

```
ol
{
   visibility: none;
}
```

I need to find this part

```
 b:hover
 {
    /*something that shows the ol list */
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `visibility` over `display`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change one element while hovering over another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

html:

```
<b> Title of the list </b>
<ol>
    <li> List item 1 </li>
    <li> list item 2 </li>
</ol>
```

css:

```
ol
{
   display:none;
}
b:hover + ol{
    display:block;
}
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/w9jTv/)

---

<sup>you can read more [here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

this is working, i prefer you use `display` instead of `visibility`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<style>
    b:hover + ol{
        display:block;
    }
    ol{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<b> Title of the list </b>
<ol>
    <li> List item 1 </li>
    <li> list item 2 </li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```