# show images when hover on link

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have 3 anchor tag and I want to show each image when hovered over an anchor tag. I attached images and reference website is http://online.wsj.com/home-page?refresh=on

```
jsexec(2, "var", function() {
    var items = dojo.query("#LSWeekend .newsItem li .selectionTarget");
    var result = new Array();
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0) {
            result[count] = dojo.query("#LSWeekend .newsItem li .selectionTarget")[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');
            count++;
        }
    }
    var dynamics = dojo.query("#LSWeekend .dynamic a");
    for (var a = 0; a < dynamics.length; a++) {
        dynamics[a].setAttribute('href', result[a]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post all the relevant code here, create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the problem (_if possible_) and be more specific.

Comment: I suggest you to provide more information about your HTML markup because probably this is possible and easier to do without javascript. Also, as you know, here is the place to ask specific questions, so it would be great if you could simplify your question and put a reproduced example on jsfiddle or so.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using the css '>' operator. (This is talked about [How to change one element while hovering over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another))

```
a > img {
    display: none;
}

a:hover > img {
    display: block;
}
```

You can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SAMdroid/VLUGM/1/

Comment: @user1596202, you can just change the css a little: http://jsfiddle.net/SAMdroid/VLUGM/4/