# targeting text in a table with :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a while now.
what i'm essentially trying to do is have the :hover pseudo-class activate
the border-bottom when i hover my cursor over the text in a table.

what it currently is doing is activating the :hover pseudo-class when i hover
in the table cell, but i only want it to activate when i hover over the text.

here's my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fbubU/1/

(for some reason the border-bottom isn't highlighting in jsfiddle)

here's some of my code

```
        <table id="navbar">
        <tr>
            <td class="nav1"></td>
            <td id="hover" class="nav2"><a href="http://www.google.com/">home</a></td>
            <td id="hover" class="nav2"><a href="http://www.google.com/">products</a></td>
            <td id="hover" class="nav2"><a href="http://www.google.com/">services</a></td>
            <td id="hover" class="nav2"><a href="http://www.google.com/">about</a></td>
            <td id="hover" class="nav2"><a href="http://www.google.com/">contact</a></td>
            <td class="nav1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


table#navbar {
border:3px solid black;
margin:0 auto;
border-collapse:collapse;
}

td.nav2 {
text-align:center;
width:100px;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}

td.nav1 {
width:243px;
}

a:visited, a:link  {
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}

td#hover:hover {
border-bottom:3px solid e8e8e8;
padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

apologies if my question isn't clear enough

edit:fixed the jsfiddle, thx for the answers everybody

edit 2: alright i think i got it working the way i want it to, again thx for the answers.

Comment: The error in Fiddle is `border-bottom: 3px solid e8e8e8;` just add hash before color code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here. First, you are repeating the same ID. Change your selecytor to  `td.nav2 a:hover` to use the class instead. Second, your color definition is missing the # before the code; without the hash means you are using a color by name (white, black, red, green blue, etc).

Your current CSS selector gets the entire `<td>`.

```
td.nav2 a:hover {
  border-bottom:3px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

will only trigger when the user hovers over the link.

Comment: He also wants to change hover from an ID to a class.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds  like you want to change the css of one element, when another is hovered over.
Here's how it can be done, revealed by a quick search:
[How to change one element while hovering over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

Where you are setting the bottom border color you have:

```
border-bottom:3px solid e8e8e8;
```

it should be:

```
border-bottom:3px solid #e8e8e8;
```

Long answer:

There are many things wrong with your code that aren't causing the error.  You should look into using lists for navigation.  Also, you have the same ID declared for every 'td'.  IDs should only be used once in your html.