# How to use css for the hover effect in another div?

Tags: html, css

so I want to eliminate the appearance of the div[ex2] on the browser size 780 and recast when the mouse point to ex div, when I open in resolution 780, div in home1/home2/profile1/profile2 is none and recast when mouse point to div ex ("ME"). sorry bad English

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 780px){   
 .ex2 ul li{
    display: none;
 }
    .ex li:hover .ex2 ul li{
    display: block;
 }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "ex">
    <li>ME</li>
</div>

<div class="ex2">
  <ul>home
    <li><a href ="#">home 1</li>
    <li><a href ="#">home 2</li>    
  </ul>
  <ul>Profile
    <li><a href ="#">Profile 1</li>
    <li><a href ="#">Profile 2</li> 
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot do this in pure css with the way your code is currently structured. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another  
You could do this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` because `ex2` next to `ex`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 780px){   
     .ex2 ul li{
        display: none;
     }
        .ex:hover + .ex2 > ul > li{
        display: block;
     }
    }
```

EDIT: working

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 780px){   
 .ex2 ul li{
    display: none;
 }
    .ex:hover + .ex2 > ul > li{
    display: block;
 }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "ex">
    <li>ME</li>
</div>

<div class="ex2">
  <ul>home
    <li><a href ="#">home 1</li>
    <li><a href ="#">home 2</li>    
  </ul>
  <ul>Profile
    <li><a href ="#">Profile 1</li>
    <li><a href ="#">Profile 2</li> 
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Vilthering check again

Comment: This will work, just be careful not to change your html layout or you'll break it. Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this by applying the `:hover` to the parent `ul` element and then using the `+` sibling selector like so. The other option is to use a JavaScript like Rohit Azad has suggested.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  .ex2 ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  .ex:hover + .ex2 ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ex">
  <li>ME</li>
</div>

<div class="ex2">
  <ul>home
    <li><a href="#">home 1</li>
    <li><a href ="#">home 2</li>    
  </ul>
  <ul>Profile
    <li><a href ="#">Profile 1</li>
    <li><a href ="#">Profile 2</li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```