# Video Play and Circle Expand Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

BACKGROUND: Hi, I wanted to make an image gallery where in when I hover I wanted 2 things to happen. The screenshot will better clarify the problem. [When I hover over the black and white image or the circle itself, the circle should expand and become a rectangle overlay.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwTKJ.png) While this is happening the video must play instead of the existing black and white image. The rectangle overlay and the video must exactly cover the black and white image.

PROBLEM: I can only get to expand the circle or play the video. Moreover when i hover over the image, the circle can't expand, I need to explicitly be hovering over circle for this to happen.

Since i am on slow connection can't upload the video for demo purpose.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 calign">

         <div class="swp_circle" id="hoverme"></div>

         <video class="thevideo" loop preload="none">
            <source src="videos/chennai_final.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
        </video>
        <div class="text_container_double" id="chennai_placename">
                <p><a href="#" class="swp_font city_name" id="chennai_link">Chennai</a></p>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0fqquuyr/

Comment: please provide some code or better yet a jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: Hey I just updated along with a fiddle.

Comment: Okay, first thing you'll have trouble with is executing css events on one element while interacting w/ another (making the circle animate while hovering over the video). This explains a way to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another

Comment: Thanks for the response. will look into it and let you know if this works.

Comment: @SandeshSubedi When do you want the video to play? when you hover over the circle overlay?

Comment: I wanted video to play as well as circle to expand on hover of the image. However my issue is solved. Thanks. Didn't see on time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use javascript to trigger your animations, because it is simpler (to my mind) to use trying to control events between elements. The answer for your circle animation at least is this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmy3evd3/2/

```
.swp_circle:hover, .hover{
   ... your css properties ...
}
```

the javascript:

```
function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $("#hoverme").addClass("hover");
    $('video', this).fadeIn('normal'); 
    //$('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    //$('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
    $("#hoverme").removeClass("hover");
    $('video', this).fadeOut('normal'); 
    $('.swp_circle',this).fadeIn('normal'); 
}
```

I commented out the video play/pause because it was throwing errors on the fiddle, but I think that part was working.

Comment: Thanks mate.. solved my issues. grateful for your support.

Comment: Great, glad it helped a bit.