# Video fluctuating on hover for Iframe

Tags: html, css

I have a div with class 'card1' and 'card2' inside which there is a iframe used. I applied hover to 'card1' and 'card2' so that it go up when I hover but the issue is when I am hovering it's fluctuating.

You will easily understand it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/scapic-hovering-cards-34xif

I tried doing pointer-events:none to the class 'video' which is inside iframe and it works fine but as pointer-event:none works, it's disabling the events.

```css
.container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .card1 {
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.5);
      border-radius: 10px;
      height: 200px;
      z-index: 1;
      margin-top: 60px;
      top: 0;
      transition: top ease 0.5s;
      transform: perspective(260px) rotateY(-28deg);
    }
    
    .card1:hover {
      top: -10px;
    }
    
    .card2 {
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      position: relative;
      transition: top ease 0.5s;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.5);
      border-radius: 10px;
      top: 0;
      height: 200px;
      transform: perspective(290px) rotateY(20deg);
    }
    
    .card2:hover {
      top: -10px;
    }
    
    .video {
      margin-top: 30px;
      border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class=container>
      <div class="card1">
        <div>
          <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" 
           src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6oFvqLfRnsU" frameborder="0" a 
           llow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in- 
           picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card2">
         <div>
           <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" 
           src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R84JU3B0jqo" frameborder="0" 
           allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in- 
           picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I want the card to stay stable when I hover and shouldn't fluctuate.

It will be a great help if anyone can help me out with this issue.

Comment: It only happens when you hover on the edge right?

Comment: No, only when I hover on the video. It works fine when I keep the cursor on the empty bar(space) above the video.

Comment: Remove hover effect for card 1 and card 2. no need to add top: -10px

Comment: It doesn't help me with hover state that pushes it up. @DDeveloper

Comment: Then how should I push it up on hover? @SangitaKendre

Comment: Hi @Sohan, (As pasanjg has asked before)are you sure the issue is happening not only in the browser "Microsoft Edge"? I've tried in "Google Chrome" and the code seems to work properly, isn't it?

Comment: @RaySoy By edge pasanjg means the corners. And the issue happens sometimes and sometimes it don't but still the issue is there. Hover for a seconds and eventually you can see the issue.

Comment: @Sohan Yes I get your point. The element goes up and down when you hover on the corner. I think it is because when you hover on the corner (as per the CSS rule) the card goes 10px up. By that time the hover gets canceled (or something) and the card returns to its original position. So this keeps happening when you keep hovering on the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out.

I placed the `card1` and `card2` in two separate containers `card1-container` and `card2-container` and added the hover effects on them to get affected on `card1` and `card2`

Also I removed the direct hover effects on `card1` and `card2`

This seems to fix the issue for me. But you can do more research improve this.

Also, [Check this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another)

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
}

.card1-container:hover>.card1 {
  top: -10px;
}

.card2-container:hover>.card2 {
  top: -10px;
}

.card1 {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 60px;
  top: 0;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transform: perspective(260px) rotateY(-28deg);
}

.card2 {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  transform: perspective(290px) rotateY(20deg);
}

.video {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card1-container">
    <div class="card1">
      <div>
        <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6oFvqLfRnsU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <!-- <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vFp2XjmoE3o" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card2-container">
    <div class="card2">
      <div>
        <!-- <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mMHEqjsbR7E" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                       -->
        <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R84JU3B0jqo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @pasanjg but it doesn't help as transform is used in the card1 and card2 and card's container is taking more space then it's suppose to be.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to solve your problem with a workaround.

What have I done? I've added two container box(one for card) between `container` and `card`. Now the event of the selector `:hover` is activated when your cursor is on the element `div` with the class `trick-container`.

How this solve the problem? When your cursor is on the element with the class `trick-container` the content inside the element is moved upper but not the element itself, in this way the selector event `:hover` isn't lost and the content isn't putted down.

HTML:

```
<div class=container>
        <div class="trick-container">
            <div class="card1-container">
                    <div class="card1">
                            <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6oFvqLfRnsU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <!-- <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vFp2XjmoE3o" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trick-container2">
            <div class="card2-container">
                <div class="card2">
                    <!-- <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mMHEqjsbR7E" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    -->
                    <iframe class="video" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R84JU3B0jqo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.trick-container {
  padding-top: 60px;
  transform: perspective(260px) rotateY(-28deg);
}
.trick-container2 {
  height: 205px;
  transform: perspective(290px) rotateY(20deg);
}

.card1-container {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
}

.trick-container:hover > .card1-container {
  top: -10px;
}

.card2-container {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
}

.trick-container2:hover > .card2-container {
  top: -10px;
}
```

You can check your reworked code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/6zilz

Let me know if this solve your problem and/or if you've solved the problem in another way!
Also ask me for further explanation if needed.