# CSS) Why is my 'hover' not working? I searched google but I couldn't fix it

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I first set `.submenu` to `display:none;`. And then I set `.recipe:hover .submenu{display:block;}` . When I hover over the `.recipe`, I wanted to make `.submenu`  `display: block;`. But it isn't working. Can you tell me why it isn't working? I can't really figure this out. Is using javascript the only way I can solve this problem? Here's my code. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</html>
<head>
    <title>
       TEST
    </title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #logo{
            height: 56px;
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-left: 45px;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
        .title{
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .mainmenu{
            border: 1px solid rgb(155,155,155);
            text-align: center;
            height: 30px;
            padding-top: 17px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: 400;
            display: flex;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding-top: 11px;
        }
        a:nth-of-type(1){
              flex-grow: 1;
            border-right: 1px solid rgb(155,155,155);
        }
        a:nth-of-type(2){
              flex-grow: 1;
            border-right: 1px solid rgb(155,155,155);
        }
        a:nth-of-type(3){
              flex-grow: 1;
        }
        .submenu{
            background-color: #f2efed;
            height: 190px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            text-decoration: underline;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 36px;
            width: 100%;
            display: none;
        }
        a{
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .recipe:hover .submenu{
            display: block;
        }
        @font-face { font-family: 'IBMPlexSansKR-Light'; src: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/projectnoonnu/noonfonts_20-07@1.0/IBMPlexSansKR-Light.woff') format('woff'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="logo">
    <img width=45px src="icons8-solo-cup-100.png">
   <span class="title">cafe in my home</span>
 </div>
   <div class="mainmenu">
       <a href="Home.html">home</a>
       <a href="Recipe.html">Recipe</a>
       <a href="QNA.html">QNA</a>
       <div class="submenu">
           coffee
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: None of the HTML elements have a `recipe` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually add the `recipe` class onto an element, then in your CSS, you need to add `~` to signify that the elements are on the same level in the DOM.

I have also made some modifications to the CSS in order to make sure the submenu does not disappear.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</html>

<head>
  <title>
    TEST
  </title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    #logo {
      height: 56px;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-left: 45px;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .title {
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    .mainmenu {
      border: 1px solid rgb(155, 155, 155);
      text-align: center;
      height: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight: 400;
      display: flex;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0px;
      padding-top: 11px;
    }
    
    a + a {
      box-shadow: -4px -3px 0 -3px rgb(155, 155, 155);
    }
    
    .submenu {
      background-color: #f2efed;
      height: 190px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 300;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 36px;
      width: 100%;
      display: none;
    }
    
    a {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      flex-grow: 1;
      height: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 6px;
    }
    
    .recipe:hover ~ .submenu {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .submenu:hover {
      display: block;
    }
    
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'IBMPlexSansKR-Light';
      src: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/projectnoonnu/noonfonts_20-07@1.0/IBMPlexSansKR-Light.woff') format('woff');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="logo">
    <img width=45px src="icons8-solo-cup-100.png">
    <span class="title">cafe in my home</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
    <a href="Home.html">home</a>
    <a href="Recipe.html" class="recipe">Recipe</a>
    <a href="QNA.html">QNA</a>
    <div class="submenu">
      coffee
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

For more information on the general sibling combinator (`~`), please read the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

Comment: Wow.. I didn't  even knew about the existence about " ~". I tried it and it works... Thank you so much. I respect your knowledge and your kindness. I will study more harder than before. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you click on the submenu? @Brian

Comment: I realized it now. The submenu is appearing when I hover, But when I try to get closer to submenu, It disappears. Do you know Why?? I'm googling now about this. Thank you.

Comment: @Brian I'm trying to fix it now ;).

Comment: @Brian I have finished making modifications.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i do it? Now I'm considering to learn javascript for my problem.

Comment: It's fixed. What exactly do you want?

Comment: Sorry. I confused it. Thank you for your comment. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the best with this, but I'd say it might have something to do with selecting the `.recipe:hover` and then selecting `.submenu` right after it:

```
    .recipe:hover .submenu{
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: I know that I should revise somthing there, but I can't realize what I should do. Can anybody explain specifically? or I just should use Javascript? Sorry for my knowledge

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your opinion was very helpful for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add !important after your code to make it principal.

```
.recipe:hover .submenu{
        display: block !important;
    }
```

Can you upload the whole code in a codeopen.io? So you can show us exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you. I tried !important, but it doesn't working. I will uploat in a codeopen.io. Thank you for your answering so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

As NoahRGB said, CSS selectors cannot have that syntax.

This:

```
.recipe:hover .submenu
```

will not work.

If you want it to select the hover of both the submenu and the recipe classes, "chain" them:

```
.recipe.submenu:hover
```

being sure not to put any spaces between `.recipe` and `.hover`.

If you wanted to set it to `display: block;` when the `.recipe` is hovered and the `.submenu` is not hovered, simply put `display: block;` in the `.submenu` class selector independently from the `.recipe:hover` selector like this:

```css
.submenu {
    ...
    display: block;
}

.recipe:hover {
    ...
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.recipe:hover .submenu{display:block;}` implies that your `.submenu` element is a child of `.recipe`.
You need to change your markup to something like:

```
<a class="recipe" href="Recipe.html">
  Recipe
  <span class="submenu">
    coffee<
  </span>
</a>
```

Or, for a fore semantic markup, especially if your sub-menu will receive more items you could do:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a class"recipe" href="Recipe.html">Recipe</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>coffee</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and change your css to:
`.menu li:hover .submenu { display:block; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do this in CSS3 now using the ~ adjacent sibling selector.

```
triggerSelector:hover ~ targetSelector {
    display: block;
}
```

as per the post [How to change one element while hovering over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another)

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</html>
<head>
    <title>
       TEST
    </title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #logo{
            height: 56px;
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-left: 45px;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        
        .title{
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .mainmenu{
            border: 1px solid rgb(155,155,155);
            text-align: center;
            height: 30px;
            padding-top: 17px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: 400;
            display: flex;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding-top: 11px;
        }
        a:nth-of-type(1){
              flex-grow: 1;
            border-right: 1px solid rgb(155,155,155);
        }
        a:nth-of-type(2){
              flex-grow: 1;
            border-right: 1px solid rgb(155,155,155);
        }
        a:nth-of-type(3){
              flex-grow: 1;
        }
        .submenu{
            background-color: #f2efed;
            height: 190px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            text-decoration: underline;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 36px;
            width: 100%;
            display: none;
        }
        a{
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .recipe:hover ~ .submenu{
            display: block;
        }
        @font-face { font-family: 'IBMPlexSansKR-Light'; src: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/projectnoonnu/noonfonts_20-07@1.0/IBMPlexSansKR-Light.woff') format('woff'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="logo">
    <img width=45px src="icons8-solo-cup-100.png">
   <span class="title">cafe in my home</span>
 </div>
   <div class="mainmenu">
       <a href="Home.html">home</a>
       <a class="recipe" href="Recipe.html">Recipe</a>
       <a href="QNA.html">QNA</a>
       <div class="submenu">
           coffee
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't hover submenu items even it is visible, It should be restructured or do it javascript way.

Answer (score 0):

You simply add ~ between selectors to adjance them together:

```
.recipe:hover ~ .submenu{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have to style your submenus in a structural way so that when you hover the element they would be visible when you try to hover submenus.

In your case submenu will get hidden if you try to make it visible. I have changed the structure a bit to show the submenu. You can more optimise it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#logo {
  height: 56px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.title {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.mainmenu {
  border: 1px solid rgb(155, 155, 155);
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 11px;
}

a:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(155, 155, 155);
}

a:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(155, 155, 155);
}

a:nth-of-type(3) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 36px;
}

.submenuwrapper {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f2efed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 190px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 40px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: none;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.recipe:hover>.submenuwrapper {
  display: block;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBMPlexSansKR-Light';
  src: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/projectnoonnu/noonfonts_20-07@1.0/IBMPlexSansKR-Light.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img width=45px src="icons8-solo-cup-100.png">
  <span class="title">cafe in my home</span>
</div>
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li><a href="Home.html">home</a></li>
  <li class="recipe"><a href="Recipe.html">Recipe</a>
    <div class="submenuwrapper">
      <div class="submenu">
        coffee
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="QNA.html">QNA</a></li>
</ul>
```